How to get greek letters with getline in c++?
I have been spending hours trying to make this work:
std::wstring string;
    getline(std::wcin, string);
    

I also tried to store the string in std::string which is the classic char and then convert it to unicode:
std::wstring uniconvert(const std::string& str) {
    return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t>{}.from_bytes(str);
}

This string is going to be a directory, so it must support Greek letters that are not "fixed", It could be any Greek letter.
Thank you.
Edit:
So after a little bit more testing, I figured out that the problem must be cmd. I used wchar_t as an argument to WriteFile and it worked perfectly. I even test wstring with DrawTextW to write on a window.
Still haven't figured how to make the cmd work though.

I just use std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);.  The Greek letters are in the line as UTF-8 encodings.

@Eljay not all of them, for some it works, for other not, for example γ,λ

What platform are you on?

@catnip windows, the problem must be cmd.

codecvt is deprecated, use OS specific functions

See linked question for an overview of what it takes, which includes setting the terminal codepage and other weird incantations.
